# Java Spring Boot Controller Unit Tests - How can I store the value of the response JSON to access it in another test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

In my Spring Boot backend application, the createUser() API Endpoint inside a controller returns a JSON containing the UUID of the new user. During testing of the controller, I want to store the string value of the id to later use it to test other API Endpoints.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc webClient;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private String createdUserId;


    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void createUser() throws Exception {
        CreateUserRequest request = CreateUserRequest.builder()
                .firstName("John")
                .lastName("Doe")
                .dateOfBirth(LocalDate.parse("2003-01-07"))
                .emailAddress("johndoe@mail.com")
                .phoneNumber("+31 633396888")
                .password("password")
                .build();

        MvcResult result = webClient.perform(post("/users")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpectAll(status().isCreated(),
                    jsonPath("$.id", Matchers.matchesPattern(
                        "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}"
                    )))
                .andReturn();

        createdUserId = JsonPath.read(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), "$.id");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void getExistingUser() throws Exception {
        webClient.perform(get("/users/" + createdUserId))
                .andExpectAll(
                    status().isOk(),
                    jsonPath("$.firstName").value("John"));
    }
}
```

While running debugger, I have noticed that during the call of createUser(), the JsonPath.read() function returns the correct UUID of the newly created user and stores it inside the createdUserId, but after finishing the call, the value gets deleted in some way.

When I build and run the whole class, the getExistingUser() test fails because the createdUserId is null.

Comment: Tests should **not** depend on the order of execution, or some state created in another test, instead mock the relevant parts when testing `getExistingUser()`. And if you are using junit (i suppose you are), each test is executed in different instance of `UserControllerTest`, so `createdUserId` being null in the get test is expected.